# Fusion Chart - 3.1.1 Can we highlight the particular bar in column 2d graph

Tags: fusioncharts

I am using `Fusion Chart version 3.1.1` and using column 2d graph in IOS which is working fine.

I am also using link event in this like given below

```
<set label="1" value="14000" color="bbdaf3" link="JavaScript:myJS1('+Salary+')"/>\n\
```

So whenever I click on this particular bar `myJS1 function` is getting called and give the result as expected.

When i click on particular bar ,  it shows its associated value which 14000 on it which default chart (Hover) functionality . Instead of Can i change the particular bar color when i click on it for **highlighting** it.

Comment: No, it is not possible to highlight a particular bar color while hovering using the latest version of FusionCharts. However, you can expect a similar feature in next upcoming release.

Comment: @Swarram Thanks , where can we find document for next release and when it is going to release.

Comment: Next release is expected around beginning of second quarter of 2014.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to change the color of particular bar while clicking on it ( with latest version of FusionCharts ). You have to modify the underlying raphael object. An example can be found in this fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/subramaniashiva/KmTZ9/6/ Let me know if this helps.

```
FusionCharts.ready(function () {
    var revenueChart = new FusionCharts({
        type: 'column2d',
        renderAt: 'chart-container',
        id: 'myChart',
        width: '500',
        height: '300',
        dataFormat: 'json',
        dataSource: {
            "chart": {
                "caption": "Quarterly Revenue ",
                    "xAxisName": "Quarter",
                    "yAxisName": "Amount (In USD)",
                    "numberPrefix": "$",
                    "valueHoverAlpha": "100",
                    "plotHoverEffect": "0",
                    "theme": "fint"
            },
                "data": [{
                "label": "Q1",
                    "value": "1950000"
            }, {
                "label": "Q2",
                    "value": "1450000"
            }, {
                "label": "Q3",
                    "value": "1730000"
            }, {
                "label": "Q4",
                    "value": "2120000"
            }]
        },
        events: {
            "dataPlotClick": function (evtObj, argObj) {
                // Modifying the underlying Raphael object
                var i, plotItems = evtObj.sender.jsVars.hcObj.elements.plots[0].items,
                    plotLength = plotItems.length;
                for (i = 0; i < plotLength; i++) {
                    plotItems[i].graphic.attr("fill-opacity", 0.2);
                }
                plotItems[argObj.dataIndex].graphic.attr("fill-opacity", 1);
            }
        }
    }).render();
});
```